# Problem with pgfornament in titlesec \titleformat

Tags: titlesec, pgfornament

I'd like to make a nice section title using the pgfornament package in the \titleformat of the titlesec package.

When I use only one ornament on the left side it works.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{pgfornament}

\begin{document}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\parbox[c]{5em}{\pgfornament[width=4em]{17}}\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}[\end{minipage}]

\chapter{Story}

\section*{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image: ornament section]

But when I want the ornament on both sides, it does not work.

```
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\parbox[c]{5em}{\pgfornament[width=4em]{17}}\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}[\end{minipage}\parbox[c]{5em}{\pgfornament[width=4em]{18}}]
```

I get the following error message from pdflatex:

```
Chapter 1.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/vectorian17.pgf)
Runaway argument?
c\@@par \ttl@endlongest \fi \endgroup \ttl@finmarks \@ifundefined {tt\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \@iparbox was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.13 \section*{Introduction}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose the whole content of the last optional argument in an extra pair of braces due to the optional arguments of the `\parbox` and of the `\pgfornament`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{pgfornament}

\begin{document}
\titleformat{\section}[block]
  {\parbox[c]{5em}{\pgfornament[width=4em]{17}}\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {\thesection}{1em}{}
  [{\end{minipage}\parbox[c]{5em}{\pgfornament[width=4em]{18}}}]
\chapter{Story}

\section*{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To prevent an overfull `\hbox`, change the width for the `minipage`; perhaps you would also like the ornament to the right to be flushed:

```
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\parbox[c]{5em}{\pgfornament[width=4em]{17}}\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-10em\relax}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
[{\end{minipage}\parbox[c]{5em}{\hfill\pgfornament[width=4em]{18}}}]
```